# Concat dataframes - One with no column name

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, concatenation

So I have 2 csv files with the same number of columns. The first csv file has its columns named (age, sex). The second file though doesn't name its columns like the first one but it's data corresponds to the according column of the first csv file. How can I concat them properly?

First csv.
[image: first csv]

Second csv.
[image: second csv]

This is how I read my files:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("input1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("input2.csv", header=None)
```

I tried using concat() like this but I get 4 columns as a result..

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: What did you try ? Please provide a reproducible example code showing where your attempts failed.

Comment: Just edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. After reading the second file I added

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
```

Works just like I wanted to. I guess I better research more next time :). Thanks

Final code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("input1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("input2.csv", header = None)
df2.columns = df1.columns
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `append` function. Be careful to have the same column names for both, otherwise you will end with 4 columns.

Check [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), I found it very useful.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("input1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("input2.csv", header = None)
df2.columns = df1.columns
df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```